# Migrating from React.js to Next.js with Typescript and Redux implemented

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, next.js

So Basically,
I have a Fully functional React app that works perfectly, and I'm trying to move to Next.js & Redux & TS.

so at some pages, I'm trying to use the useEffect method to dispatch some async redux actions that are in charge of fetching some data for me, and when I moved this to next (copy-paste)

it doesn't work and it gives me 404 for all of my end-points, something is off, maybe next implements it differently,

but how should I dispatch an async action with next before the page gets displayed?

Comment: Do the existing API routes begin with `/api/*` by any chance?

Comment: yes, it containes it, something like this 'https:hosting/api/fetchdata'

Comment: implementation of redux in next.js is different. https://www.quintessential.gr/blog/development/how-to-integrate-redux-with-next-js-and-ssr

Comment: @kyrolos So `/api/*` is special in Next.js and is considered an [API Route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction). It will get mapped to the `pages/api` directory in your project. For a workaround, see: [vercel/next.js/discussions/13346#discussioncomment-18263](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13346#discussioncomment-18263)